# Is there any algorithm in c# to singularize - pluralize a word?

Tags: c#, algorithm

Is there any algorithm in c# to singularize - pluralize a word (in english) or does exist a .net library to do this (may be also in different languages)?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

You also have the [System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.aspx).

**UPDATE**: Old answer deserves update. There's now also Humanizer: https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer

Comment: Hmmm are you allow to redistribute, or just use, a Design DLL? I ask that because I know that the license for DevExpress prohibit redistributing any .design DLL.

Comment: Opening the code with ILSpy shows a class called EnglishPluralizationService, which has lots of exceptional cases defined in and makes for interesting reading. I particularly like 'pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis', which I find myself using all the time in my entity models... 8o)

Comment: I can guess how that got added. A tester filed a bug on the dev saying it does not work for the said word. Dev fixed it. Both shared a laugh.

Comment: @MrKWatkins Sounds more like 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious'

Comment: Humanizer is a great recommendation.  I'd of course implemented like 15% of it myself before finding out it existed.

Comment: PluralizationService fails on "Courses". It singularizes to "Cours".

Answer (score 19):

I can do it for Esperanto, with no special cases!

```
string plural(string noun) { return noun + "j"; }
```

For English, it would be useful to become familiar with the rules for [Regular Plurals of Nouns](http://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/330/grammar/plural.htm), as well as [Irregular Plurals of Nouns](http://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/330/grammar/irrplu.htm). There is a whole Wikipedia article on the [English plural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plural), which may have some helpful information too.

Comment: You should make it throw if you pass in a verb or adverb!

Comment: @Matt: Of course this is appropriate for the nominative case; I trust that extending this method to the accusative case is straightforward for an astute reader.

Answer (score 14):

Most ORMs have a stab at it, although they generally aren't perfect. I know Castle has it's [Inflector Class](http://api.castleproject.org/html/T_Castle_ActiveRecord_Framework_Internal_Inflector.htm) you can probably poke around. Doing it "perfectly" isn't an easy task though (English "rules" aren't really rules :)), so it depends if you are happy with a "reasonable guess" approach.

Comment: From your suggestion I searched for "Inflector" and found this http://andrewpeters.net/inflectornet/ that sould basically be the same of the Castle one

Comment: Actually its not basically the same, its identical.

Answer (score 12):

I cheated in Java - I wanted to be able to produce a correct string for "There were n something(s)", so I wrote the foll. little overloaded utility method:

```
static public String pluralize(int val, String sng) {
    return pluralize(val,sng,(sng+"s"));
    }

static public String pluralize(int val, String sng, String plu) {
    return (val+" "+(val==1 ? sng : plu)); 
    }
```

invoked like so

```
System.out.println("There were "+pluralize(count,"something"));
System.out.println("You have broken "+pluralize(count,"knife","knives"));
```

Comment: This only covers a small sections of grammar though, it doesn't account for words like quizzes, parties, halves, mice, indices, etc. It's a good first stab, but there are a lot of other rules that should probably be processed first.

Comment: @Jeremy: Why not?: println("You have passed " + singularPlural(count,"quiz","quizzes") + " so far")

Comment: I might be interpreting the question differently. I'm thinking the algorithm should be determining the plural form without any hint from the developer, while your method puts the onus of knowing what the plural form is on the developer.

Comment: @Jeremy: Hence the "I cheated..." lead in - doesn't seem to warrant a downvote.

Comment: Agreed. I also think the information provided was useful, which is why any downvote didn't come from me. I don't downvote in general, along the lines of the "one man's junk...".

Comment: Just wait till you have to localize this into different languages. I would rather avoid the problem and do `Number of something: n`

Comment: @Kugel: Been there done that, and this method is not relevant for NLS support, only for a very simple *possible* solution to the question posed by the OP (which specifically restricted things to English).

Comment: I had to read this several times to realize what the parameter names were meant to be and thus what the method actually does. Characters are free. Naming the parameters `singular` and `plural` would have made the method 100X more clear.

Comment: @MgSam : Characters might be free, but my time is not -- please don't waste it by making comments about debatable matters of style.

Answer (score 10):

I've created a tiny library for this in .net (C#), called Pluralizer (unsurprisingly).

It's meant to work with full sentences, something like String.Format does.

It basically works like this:

```
var target = new Pluralizer();
var str = "There {is} {_} {person}.";

var single = target.Pluralize(str, 1);
Assert.AreEqual("There is 1 person.", single);

// Or use the singleton if you're feeling dirty:
var several = Pluralizer.Instance.Pluralize(str, 47);
Assert.AreEqual("There are 47 people.", several);
```

It can also do way more than that. Read more about it [on my blog](http://jasonq.com/index.php/pluralizer). It's also available in NuGet.

Comment: Any advantage over [System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.aspx)?

Comment: Yup, that library only does single words, and only nouns (although Pluralizer uses that class internally). This library makes to make whole sentences easier to write. Have a look at my blog for more examples.

Pluralizer.Instance.Pluralize("{She} {is} going to {her|their respective} {home}.", 5)

Comment: Shaun Wilson - My computer is currently in parts. I'm rushing to get it back up and will update within a day or two. 

In the mean time, http://nuget.org/packages?q=pluralizer

Answer (score 8):

I whipped one together based on the Rails pluralizer.  You can see my blog post [here](http://mattgrande.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/pluralization-helper-for-c/), or [on github here](https://github.com/mattgrande/Grande.Pluralizer)

```
output = Formatting.Pluralization(100, "sausage");
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Glad I didn't need to reference another assembly.

Comment: Simple and beautiful!, but it misses the **Singularize** functionality

Answer (score 5):

As the question was for C#, here is a nice variation on Software Monkey's solution (again a bit of a "cheat", but for me really the most practical and reusable way of doing this):

```
    public static string Pluralize(this string singularForm, int howMany)
    {
        return singularForm.Pluralize(howMany, singularForm + "s");
    }

    public static string Pluralize(this string singularForm, int howMany, string pluralForm)
    {
        return howMany == 1 ? singularForm : pluralForm;
    }
```

The usage is as follows:

```
"Item".Pluralize(1) = "Item"
"Item".Pluralize(2) = "Items"

"Person".Pluralize(1, "People") = "Person"
"Person".Pluralize(2, "People") = "People"
```

Answer (score 4):

Subsonic 3 has an [`Inflector`](http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/blob/c8a7add431114f0382bdaa33f7aedbaab7d89ba7/SubSonic.Core/Extensions/Inflector.cs) class which impressed me by turning `Person` into `People`. I peeked at the source and found it naturally cheats a little with a hardcoded list but that's really the only way of doing it in English and how humans do it - we remember the singular and plural of each word and don't just apply a rule. As there's not masculine/feminine(/neutral) to add to the mix it's a lot simpler.

Here's a snippet:

```
AddSingularRule("^(ox)en", "$1");
AddSingularRule("(vert|ind)ices$", "$1ex");
AddSingularRule("(matr)ices$", "$1ix");
AddSingularRule("(quiz)zes$", "$1");

AddIrregularRule("person", "people");
AddIrregularRule("man", "men");
AddIrregularRule("child", "children");
AddIrregularRule("sex", "sexes");
AddIrregularRule("tax", "taxes");
AddIrregularRule("move", "moves");

AddUnknownCountRule("equipment");
```

It accounts for some words not having plural equivalents, like the equipment example. As you can probably tell it does a simple `Regex` replace using $1.

**Update:**
It appears Subsonic's `Inflector` is infact the [Castle ActiveRecord `Inflector`](https://svn.castleproject.org/svn/castle/trunk/ActiveRecord/Castle.ActiveRecord/Framework/Internal/Inflector.cs) class!

Answer (score 3):

Not much documentation from MSDN on the specific usage of the PluralizationService class so here is a unit test class (NUnit) to show basic usage. Notice the odd test case at the bottom that shows the service isn't perfect when it comes to non-standard plural forms.

```
[TestFixture]
public class PluralizationServiceTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test01()
    {
        var service = PluralizationService.CreateService(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        Assert.AreEqual("tigers", service.Pluralize("tiger"));
        Assert.AreEqual("processes", service.Pluralize("process"));
        Assert.AreEqual("fungi", service.Pluralize("fungus"));

        Assert.AreNotEqual("syllabi", service.Pluralize("syllabus")); // wrong pluralization
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Microsoft's Northwind example database:

```
 System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService.CreateService(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Singularize does not Singularize "Order_Details" 
It returns "Order_Details" with the `s` at the end. What is the work around?

Comment: This is a question, not an answer to a question... but Pluralize() and Singularize() only work with dictionary words. There's a way to add words using ICustomPluralizationMapping.AddWord, but at least for me that wasn't a very good solution when you may have lots of not-real words like code names.

Comment: @tordal Thank you, this is exactly what I came to this question for

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PluralizationService` of `System.Data.Entity` (.NET Framework 4.0), as shown in this page:
http://zquanghoangz.blogspot.it/2012/02/beginner-with-pluralizationservices.html