# Pluralize English words Like LINQ to SQL Does

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, pluralize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pluralize - Singularize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475705/pluralize-singularize)

The C# 4.0 (maybe older versions, but I've only tested with 4.0) Linq-to-SQL generator will pluralize your table names; even tough plurals like Territory.  It knows that Territories is the plural.  Is there anyway to access this pluralization function?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Interesting first question!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.aspx)

EDIT Linking the [(older) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475705/pluralize-singularize/2405297#2405297) in the (older) question, as eglasias suggests.  Go forth and upvote, he deserves the rep.

Comment: Why are there more upvotes for my answer than people voting to mark the question as a duplicate?

Comment: Because it's a whole lot easier to click on the "good answer" button?  There's no "mark as duplicate" button immediately visible.

Comment: Because the second mouse gets the cheese.  In the old post, Daniel gave the same answer, got 1 upvote, and has 86 reputation at the time that this is being written.  Life can be SO unfair.

Comment: Come on. Obviously it’s because only like 1% of SO users have enough rep to vote to close.

Comment: @Timwi Wow, your approximation was spot on. 1.44% to be more exact.

Comment: @Ben: because I don't think it's a duplicate, since it is about the LINQ to SQL algorithm, not just general.

Comment: There, 1 more vote to close as duplicate without voting for this answer / also 1 more vote to the answer in the other/original question. imho when doing this you should always link to the other answer as well in here.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, possibly because you linked to the documentation and he just gave class name. He'll learn.

Comment: @John: It is a duplicate because the requirement for being closed as a duplicate is that the question has been fully covered by an earlier question, not that both questions have identical scope.  The other question and answers completely cover this one.

Comment: @Ben: I didn't see Daniel's answer first time. Voted to close. Also, upvoted Daniel's answer and edited it to include link to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the Linq to SQL inflector is publicly accessible, but if you need an inflector you could use [SubSonic's inflector](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Helpers/Inflector.cs?r=296629cb4da8cb9a2332317fb81d87b2710a2a17), [NCommon](http://ncommon.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/28264#358147), [uNhAddins](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/source/browse/#svn/trunk/uNhAddIns/uNhAddIns/Inflector), [Castle ActiveRecord](http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.ActiveRecord/blob/master/src/Castle.ActiveRecord/Framework/Internal/Inflector.cs), etc.