# Silverlight 4 and the System.Data.Entity.Design Namespace

Tags: c#, entity-framework, silverlight

### BACKGROUND

I'm trying to write some string extension methods that utilize the following methods out of the [**PluralizationService Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice(v=vs.100).aspx):

> [**`PluralizationService.IsPlural()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.isplural(v=vs.100).aspx)
>
> [**`PluralizationService.IsSingular()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.issingular(v=vs.100).aspx)
>
> [**`PluralizationService.Pluralize()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.pluralize(v=vs.100).aspx)
>
> [**`PluralizationService.Singularize()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.singularize(v=vs.100).aspx)

---

### EXTENSION METHODS

```cs
public static string Pluralize(this string word)
{
    var svc = PluralizationService.CreateService(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
    return svc.IsSingular(word) ? svc.Pluralize(word) : word;
}

public static string Singularize(this string word)
{
    var svc = PluralizationService.CreateService(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
    return svc.IsPlural(word) ? svc.Singularize(word) : word;
}
```

---

### PROBLEM

In **Silverlight 4** I'm not able to see the [**System.Data.Entity.Design**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design(v=vs.100).aspx) Namespace when choosing references.  How can I reference this and use my extension methods?

Comment: EF never shipped with Silverlight. You may have more luck with EF6 which is bin deployable but am not sure if it can work with Silverlight. On the other hand attaching a 5MB dll is kind of overkill if you just need it for pluralization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, entity framework is likely not included in Silverlight. There are other alternatives that exist already that could be used in silverlight (likely). [Check out this other answer for other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475705/pluralize-singularize) like subsonic's pluralizer or castle's inflector

Comment: Yea, I looked at that post prior to posting.  I didn't see anything I liked.  I used [ILSpy](http://www.ilspy.net) to decompile the `PluralizationService` class.  Maybe I can piece together something from that.

Comment: Yeah there shouldn't be that much to it, especially if you only need it for one language. Best of luck