# c# mvc get generic type using reflection

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection

Currently trying to find a way to get the type of a generically typed class and have been unable to find a way to do so. My current, working method looks as follows:

```
public class CategoryConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
    {
        public CategoryConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("Categories");
            Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
        }
    }
```

and I'd like to change this method to be something like:

```
public class CategoryConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<T>
    {
        public CategoryConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable(/*get string representation of 'T' here and pluralize*/);
            Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you can do:

```
ToTable(typeOf(T).Name);
```

And about pluralization please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2405297/3596441)

Comment: in C#6.0 you can use nameof(T)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to see a class name, use `nameof(T)`. Or, if you would like to see different name bounding with `T` type, you can use an `Attribute`, `Description` for example (read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), and get value of it.

For example:

```
[Description("/*name, which you would like to see*/")]
public class Category
{
    /* your class realization */
}
```

And in `CategoryConfiguration` use

```
ToTable((typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true)
                  .First() as DescriptionAttribute)
                  .Description);
```